# Error report - ORA-00904: : invalid identifier 00904. 00000 - "%s: invalid identifier"

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my SQL Oracle script and I cannot figure out why I keep getting the following error when I try and run this code:
I keep getting this exact code on each table I try to run. Can anyone point me in the right direction as to why my code will not run? I have tried researching this myself ALL DAY LONG and cant get it.**

```
Error starting at line : 12 in command -
CREATE TABLE COURSE (
CRS_CODE        VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
CRS_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT    CRS_CREDIT    NOT NULL,
CHECK (CRS_CREDIT IN (1,2,3,4)),
PRIMARY KEY   (CRS_CODE))
Error report -
ORA-00904: : invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
SQL> 


**CODE BEFORE ERROR:**
/* This script file creates the following tables:*/
/*COURSE, CLASS, ENROLL, STUDENT */

set echo on;
set serveroutput on ;

/*DROP TABLE COURSE;
DROP TABLE CLASS;
DROP TABLE STUDENT;
DROP TABLE ENROLL;*/

CREATE TABLE COURSE (
CRS_CODE        VARCHAR (8) NOT NULL,
CRS_DESCRIPTION VARCHAR (35) NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT    CRS_CREDIT    NOT NULL,
CHECK (CRS_CREDIT IN (1,2,3,4)),
PRIMARY KEY   (CRS_CODE));

CREATE TABLE CLASS (
CLASS_CODE  NUMBER (5)  NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT CLASS_SECTION_Ck NOT NULL,
CLASS_TIME  VARCHAR (25)    NOT NULL,
CLASS_ROOM  CHAR (6),
CHECK (CLASS_SECTION IN (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)),
PRIMARY KEY (CLASS_CODE),
FOREIGN KEY (CRS_CODE) REFERENCES COURSE (CRS_CODE));

CREATE TABLE STUDENT (
STU_NUM     INTEGER NOT NULL,
STU_LNAME   VARCHAR (25) NOT NULL,
STU_FNAME   VARCHAR (20) NOT NULL,
STU_INIT    CHAR  (1),
STU_DOB     DATE    NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINTS STU_HRS_Ck  DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
STU_CLASS   CHARACTER(2) REFERENCES "Fr", "So", "Jr", "Gr" NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT  STU_GPA_Ck  DEFAULT 0.00 NOT NULL,
STU_PHONE   VARCHAR (4)  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (STU_NUM),
CHECK (STU_HRS <= 0),
CHECK (STU_HRS >= 1000),
CHECK (STU_GPA BETWEEN 0.00 AND 4.00));

CREATE TABLE ENROLL (
ENROLL_GRADE_Ck     VARCHAR (1) REFERENCES "A","B","C","D","F","I","W", "Z", DEFAULT Z NOT NULL,
FOREIGN KEY (STU_NUM) REFERENCES STUDENT (STU_NUM),
FOREIGN KEY (CLASS_CODE) REFERENCES CLASS (CLASS_CODE),
PRIMARY KEY (CLASS_CODE));

commit;
```

Comment: I am just curious what the error message means.

Comment: The error message means Oracle is confused. It seems you want to define a third column in the table, with the name CRS_CREDIT, probably of data type NUMBER (but that is not included anywhere in your definition), and you want it to be NOT NULL. That is fine - the correct syntax is, after the comma for CRS_DESCRIPTION, type `CRS_CREDIT NUMBER NOT NULL,` and then the CHECK constraint. In your table definition, if Oracle encounters key words like PRIMARY (for PRIMARY KEY) or CHECK (for a check constraint), it knows you are done defining columns. But CONSTRAINT in that position is not a keyword.

Comment: Oracle interprets it as an attempt on your part to define a **column** with the name CONSTRAINT. But CONSTRAINT **is**, in fact, an Oracle reserved work, you can't use it as a column name. (CONSTRAINT is a reserved keyword, just not in that position - wrong syntax). So it complains that you are trying to define a column with the name CONSTRAINT. It would "complain" with **exactly** the same error if you change the word CONSTRAINT to DATE or TABLE - they are not allowed to be column names. If you change it to CRS_BRITTNI, you will get a different error message (since the syntax is still wrong).

Comment: Thank you so very very very much for your comment! Ok so just to be clea (sorry) I need to just define the column and then use CHECK. There is not need for the word "CONSTRAINT" in front of it?

Comment: Ohhhhhh ok so in this case I need it to be an INTEGER so I will fix it to: CRS_CREDIT INTEGER NOT NULL,
CHECK (CRS_CREDIT IN (1,2,3,4)),

Answer (score 0):

It is not clear from your question whether you are trying to create a COLUMN level CONSTRAINT or not.  If you are trying to create a COLUMN level CONSTRAINT, then there seems to be a syntax error in your CONSTRAINT  definition (a comma before the word CONSTRAINT).

See the following link from Oracle:
**https://docs.oracle.com/javadb/10.8.3.0/ref/rrefsqlj13590.html**

It has examples on how to define constraints including COLUMN level constraints.  You may want to compare your CONSTRAINT clause with the examples to see if there are errors in your CONSTRAINTS.

Comment: The OP is trying to put a constraint on CRS_CREDIT, a column name that has not been defined anywhere. There is, indeed, a syntax error, but not the one you suggested.

Comment: Even when I fixed this issue, I am getting the same darn error.

Comment: Yes, the constraint is on a column that was not defined and that combined with the CONSTRAINT clause referencing it causes the error.  Can you update your statement to what it is now so we can determine the new issue?